# Can I ask ui-router to update a specific resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have some resolves in a state and I want to update the data for one specific resolve.

For example, I want to update only `Resolve1` (in the following example) from within `mainController` or from a child state of `main`:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('main', {
        url: '',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: ...
        controller: mainController,
        resolve: {
            Resolve1: ...
            Resolve2: ...
        }
    })
```

Calling `$state.reload()` loads all the data again.

Is there a way to reload only the data for `Resolve1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider moving your data fetching and updating calls into a factory/service/provider.  Using the data in a factory/service/provider will allow you to call to refresh the data from wherever you need to.

Comment: Yes, that was my thought too. But the project I work on uses this style (resolves) as a rule everywhere and I want to avoid changing the (probably wrong) way of doing things. :(

Comment: yeah I've been on similar projects where they had used resolves for everything and then wanted the views to change before data was loaded which made it a huge refactor, but it would make this a null and void problem to just have the call to get data contained in a factory (could still get data into the controller via a resolve if that's desired as well)